# How do I test a value on a list of objects using jsRender

Tags: javascript, jsrender

I'm new to jsRender. On my Model I have something like:

```
public List<BasketOptions> Basket {get; set;}
```

I know in jsRender for example I can do:

```
{{if Basket.length }}
```

which will return true or false if I have at Basket.

what I'm trying to do and need some help with is that on my BasketOptions object I have a boolean 'Selected' flag. I need to be able to test for any selected flag being true. can anybody offer or point me to a good example of how to do this. I'm assuming I need to call a Javascript function passing my Basket object and determining the value there, but it's how I call that javascript function and return the value for jsRender to test.

So I have created a javascript function:

```
<script>
   function GetBasketSelected(options) {
   var optionSelected = options.find(function (option) {
     return option.Selected;
   });
   return optionSelected;
}
</script>
```

and to call the script I have:

```
{{ if ~GetBasketSelected(Basket) }}
……
{{/if}}
```

I set a breakpoint in the javascript function in chrome browser and it never gets hit.

So I have also tried the following without luck:

```
{{ if :~GetBasketSelected(Basket) }}
    ……
{{/if}}
```

with

```
<script>
   $.views.helpers({
       GetBasketSelected: function(options) {
       var optionSelected = options.find(function (option) {
         return option.Selected;
       });
       return optionSelected;
    }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Ah, so Basket is an array. I didn't notice that. But your syntax is wrong, No space here after the curly brackets: `{{ if... `. Should be `{{if ~GetBasketSelected(Basket) }}`. If that still does not work, create a jsfiddle and I'll take a look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Selected is a property of Basket, you can write

```
{{if Basket.Selected}}...{{/if}}
```

or

```
{{if Basket.Selected===true}}...{{/if}}
```

But if Selected is a getter function, you would need

```
{{if Basket.Selected()}}...{{/if}}
```

You can also call [helper](https://www.jsviews.com/#helpers) functions:

```
{{if ~testSelected(Basket)}}...{{/if}}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. The last one looked like the type of thing I need to be doing, but it doesn't work for me. I've amended my question based on this.